# Does it matter if the shunt resistor in an audio Line Out L-Pad attenuator is 6 feet away from the series resister?

Tags: amplifier, analog, audio, signal-integrity, attenuator

I am designing a 14dB L-Pad attenuator to be buried in a guitar instrument cable as per below.

The placement of the 22K ohm series resistor is to go inline inside the amplifier side of the 1/4" mono plug. I would like to place the 5.6K shunt resister parallel inside the other cable end.

I could try to get them both at the amp side of the cable but that is a tight squeeze in the small small space inside the plug.

Does the placement of the shunt at the other end of the 6-foot cable change the tone or have any other detrimental impact?

---

```
Specifications
Pad = -13.89dB
R1 = 22K, R2 = 5.6K
Circuit impedance = 27.569K ohms
Vout = 1.223V rms, Vin = 0.247V rms
Cable: 6' instrument shielded. Two parallel for stereo.
Amplifier Line Out Z= 600 ohms.
Effects pedal input is 1M ohms.
There will be two cables since this is a stereo in/out setup.
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a relevance for the signal being that of a guitar given that you show a line out with 600 ohms? I mention this because you wouldn't be able to use this modified cable directly into a guitar.

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have said. This is just to pad the amplifier Line Level output into the Instrument pedal input. Said padded-cable will have obvious tags that they should only be used for this and which end goes into the amp.

Comment: Also wondering, if I chose a 10K and 2.2K, then I get -15 dB. Then the shunt is only 2.2K and the overall impedance is now closer to 10K. However, I think the 22K one provides a little extra impedance and that helps reduce the workload on the amp circuit when it is cranked? Just wondering.

Comment: It's not going to make much difference either way realistically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the placement of the shunt at the other end of the 6 foot cable
> change the tone or have any other detrimental impact?

No, I don't believe this will be a problem.

6 foot (say 2 metres) will have a capacitance of around 200 to 300 pF so, worst case low pass roll-off will occur at: -

$$f = \dfrac{1}{2\pi R C}\hspace{1cm} = \text{ 24 kHz}$$

But this assumes the 5k6 resistor is open circuit so, in reality it will be circa 100 kHz and not an issue for audio.

Comment: So that's cable capacitance related and not any ill-effect of the shunt being at the other end, correct?

Comment: @TheCoordinator correct.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @TheCoordinator [Take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to give thanks in the accepted way. Oh, I see you already know how to do this on your question yesterday.